# Как работать со специальными символами в json при асинхронном запросе?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, xmlhttprequest

Пытаюсь получить строку из MySQL таблицы, которая содержит символ перевода строки `\n`. При передаче через асинхронный запрос этой строки (использую `json`) - получаю `null` в `xhr.response`. Обычные строки передаются нормально - но стоит появиться хоть одному специальному символу - получаю `null`;

**Что я могу сделать чтобы и `null` не получать и понимать где в тексте перевод строки???**

P.S. 5я и 6я строки в таблице содержат символ перевода строки `\n`

Структура папок

```
.
├── app
│   ├── core
│   │   └── Router.php
│   └── view
│       └── default.php
├── index.php
└── js
    └── test.js
```

Код

index.php

```php
<?php
    require_once __DIR__ . '/app/core/Router.php';

    $router = new Router;
    $router->getPage();
```

Router.php

```php
<?php
    class Router {
        public array $request;

        public function __construct() {
            $this->request = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        }

        public function getPage(): void {
            switch($this->request[1]) {
                case 'test':
                    $mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'KisaragiEki4', 'Test');
                    $query = <<<END
                    select some_text from test where id = 6
                    END;
                    $data = $mysql->query($query);
                    foreach($data as $row) {
                        echo <<<END
                        {
                            "some_text": "{$row['some_text']}"
                        }
                        END;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    include_once __DIR__ . '/../view/default.php';
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

default.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Я стартовая страница</h1>
        <button class="button" onclick="getMysqlData();">button</button>
        <template class="template">
            <p></p>
        </template>
        <script src="js/test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

test.js

```js
function getMysqlData() {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'test');
    xhr.send();
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onload = () => {
        alert(xhr.response);
        let template = document.querySelector('.template');
        let element = template.content.cloneNode(true);
        text = xhr.response['some_text'];
        element.append(text);
        document.body.append(element);
    };
}
```

Содержание таблицы в MySQL

```
mysql> select * from test;
+----+-------------+
| id | some_text   |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | hello       |
|  2 | hello       |
|  3 | hello       |
|  4 | hello
      |
|  5 | hello
hello |
|  6 | hi
hello    |
+----+-------------+
6 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: *P.S. 5я и 6я строки в таблице содержат символ перевода строки `\n`* Четвёртая тоже - это хорошо видно. Её значение принимается нормально?

Comment: @Akina, забыл просто про нее) с ней такая же история

Comment: Если изменить форматирование результата и получать его в виде строки, а не JSON - получаете значение нормально, или так же NULL?

Comment: @Akina, со стороны сервера приходит все хорошо, также если указываю тип возвращаемого ответа в формате текста (`xhr.responseType = 'json';`) - алерт все отлично показывает. Ошибка возникает когда я пытаюсь преобразовать `json` уже конкретно в обьект. Я понимаю что можно перед отправкой ответа клиенту заменить `\n` на какой-нибудь `<-|n|->`(условно), и после получения уже на стороне клиента обратно это все преобразовывать. Но как мне кажется это тот еще костыль. Нет ли какого-нибудь более практичного решения, просто я не думаю что подобного рода костыли будут приветсвоваться в продакшене.

Comment: *Ошибка возникает когда я пытаюсь преобразовать json уже конкретно в обьект.* Ну, значит, надо разобраться, что должно быть в JSON вместо `\n`, чтобы преобразовывалось корректно... например, может потребоваться удвоение слэша. Если в языке есть обратное преобразование - JSON в текст,- то проделай его и посмотри, что получилось в JSON..

Comment: См. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068/how-do-i-handle-newlines-in-json

Comment: Очевидно что проблема решается использованием `json_encode`, а не вот этой шляпы с `<<<END{  }END`.